# Throwing exceptions in Spring AOP

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

Every time I read the official Spring AOP documentation ([link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop-api.html)), I get confused by the behavior of advices wrt RuntimeExceptions. Would someone check if my undestanding is correct for the following advices?

@Before

- Advice throws Exception = Target (not executed) Advice (executed)
- Target throws Exception = Target (executed) Advice (executed)

@AfterReturning

- Advice throws Exception = Target (executed) Advice (executed)
- Target throws Exception = Target (executed) Advice (not executed)

@AfterThrowing

- Advice throws Exception = Target (executed) Advice (not executed)
- Target throws Exception = Target (executed) Advice (executed)

@After

- Advice throws Exception = Target (executed) Advice (executed)
- Target throws Exception = Target (executed) Advice (executed)

@Around

- Advice throws Exception = Target (executed) Advice (executed)
- Target throws Exception = Target (executed) Advice (executed up to point.proceed())

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how I usually look at it.

```
try {
    //@Before
    method();
    //@AfterReturning
} catch(Throwable t) {
    //@AfterThrowing
} finally {
    //@After
}
```

`@Around` is kind of its own beast.  Since you choose when to invoke the target, you are able to catch any `Exception`'s it may `throw`.  Therefore, you can easily wrap the call in a `try-catch-finally` and have access to any and all of the joinpoints previously mentioned.

I am assuming that when you say 'executed', you mean 'executed to the point that the exception was thrown'.

Another thing that may be important to you is the `@Order` annotation.  Higher valued `@Order`'s occur first on the before side, and they work themselves out backwards on the after side.  Make sure you keep that in mind when combining multiple Advices to the same target.

Comment: excellent advice on @Around and well noted on @Order; regarding the other Advices, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, it looks to be correct.  As long as you mean 'executed to the point the exception was thrown' in the applicable cases.

Comment: that is precisely what I mean, I was just trying to be succinct